# Diagnosing MATLAB MySQL JDBC Driver Error (Windows)

Tags: matlab, jdbc

Attempts, from MATLAB R2017a Windows-7, to connect to a database fail.

```
conn = database(dbsource,username,password,'Vendor','MySQL', 'Server','mysql8.db4free.net','portnumber',3306)
```

Error message: **Unable to find JDBC driver**

[image]

The [JDBC driver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-windows.html) was:

- copied from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=477058
- copied to C:\drivers\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar
- added to the JDBC static path
- path \ filename was verified:

[image]

1. Is there enough information here to diagnose the root cause of the error message?
2. What is the root cause and corrective action?
3. Why does MATLAB indicate the JDBC driver file is not on the java classpath?  Remedy?

Responses to requests for additional diagnostic information will be added to the original posting.

Attempts to try these JDBC drivers were unsuccessful by individually testing each of these files in javaclass path:

1. C:\drivers\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6-bin.jar
2. C:\drivers\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

JDBC Driver 'Installation' of these comprises

1. Unzipping the .jar driver to the target director
2. Ensuring C:\Path\driver.jar is in MATLAB's javaclasspath
3. Verifying that javaclasspath return C:\Path\driver.jar
4. Verifying that C:\Path\driver.jar (returned in Step 3) at MATLAB prompt

   >> dir('C:\drivers\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6-bin.jar')

Attempt to configure MATLAB's database explorer app returned the message:

```
 JDBC driver file was not found on MATLAB java classpath
```

[image]

Java version:

[image]

Comment: How did you try and connect to the database? According to this [page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database-connection-error-messages.html) that error can be caused by:
"Incorrect driver name provided while using the 'driver' and 'url' syntax."

Comment: OP updated: the database() statement was tested \  verified on an OSX box

Comment: Any startup errors regarding the class path? I presume you've restarted MATLAB? Also is the jar file okay? Try opening it with a zip-file reader?

Comment: No startup errors after several restarts.  What is the procedure / criteria to verify jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed your error message by using mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar with MATLAB R2017a.

[This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) describes that Connector/J 8.0 (including mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar) supports only JRE 1.8.x. But MATLAB R2017a uses JRE 1.7, so mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar is not supported in R2017a.

There are three options for you.

1. Use Connector/J 5.1

   Connector/J 5.1 supports JRE 1.7, so it works with MATLAB R2017a and also it supports MySQL Server 8.0. You can download Connector/J 5.1 from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html).
2. Update MATLAB to R2017b or R2018a

   From R2017b, MATLAB uses JRE 1.8, so it works with Connector/J 8.0, including mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar which you already have.
3. Change Java version in MATLAB
   I will not recommend this approach, but you can change Java version of MATLAB from 1.7 to 1.8 and it would work with mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar. For detail, please see [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130359).

Comment: ありがと  Excellent research and I like how you presented multiple options.  The simple solution I chose is  to use 5.1

Comment: weirdly enough [this is still not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51722966/6717178).